# Keras fit_generator() not working due to shape error

Tags: keras

I am running MNIST prediction using Keras, with tensorflow backend.
I have code that runs with batches , using Keras **fit()** as

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

N1 = X_train.shape[0]  
N2 = X_test.shape[0]  
h = X_train.shape[1]
w = X_train.shape[2]

num_pixels = h*w
# reshape N1 samples to num_pixels
x_train = X_train.reshape(N1, num_pixels).astype('float32') # shape is now (60000,784)
x_test = X_test.reshape(N2, num_pixels).astype('float32') # shape is now (10000,784)

x_train = x_train / 255
x_test = x_test / 255

y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train) #(60000,10)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test) # (10000,10): 
num_classes = y_test.shape[1]


def baseline_model():
# create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(num_pixels, input_dim=num_pixels, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))    
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
model = baseline_model()
batch_size = 200
epochs = 20
max_batches = 2 * len(x_train) / batch_size # 2*60000/200

# reshape to be [samples][width][height][ channel] for ImageDataGenerator
x_t = X_train.reshape(N1, w, h, 1).astype('float32')
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale= 1./255)
train_gen = datagen.flow(x_t, y_train, batch_size=batch_size)
for e in range(epochs):
    batches = 0
    for x_batch, y_batch in train_gen:
    # x_batch is of size [batch_sz,w,h,ch]: resize to [bth_sz,pixel_sz]: (200,28,28,1)-> (200,784)
    # for model.fit
        x_batch = np.reshape(x_batch, [-1, num_pixels])            
        model.fit(x_batch, y_batch,validation_split=0.15,verbose=0)
        batches += 1
        print("Epoch %d/%d, Batch %d/%d" % (e+1, epochs, batches, max_batches))
        if batches >= max_batches:
            break

scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
```

However, when I try to implement similar code using **fit_generator()**, I get an error.
the code is as below:

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
# separate data into train and validation
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# Split the data
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.15, shuffle= True)

# number of training samples
N1 = X_train.shape[0]  # training size
N2 = X_test.shape[0]   # test size
N3 = X_valid.shape[0]  # valid size
h = X_train.shape[1]
w = X_train.shape[2]

num_pixels = h*w

y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train) 
y_valid = np_utils.to_categorical(y_valid)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test) 

num_classes = y_test.shape[1]

def baseline_model():
# create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(num_pixels, input_dim=num_pixels, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))   
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model = baseline_model()

batch_size = 200
epochs = 20
steps_per_epoch_tr = int(N1/ batch_size) # 51000/200
steps_per_epoch_val =  int(N3/batch_size) 

# reshape to be [samples][width][height][ channel] for ImageData Gnerator->datagen.flow
x_t = X_train.reshape(N1, w, h, 1).astype('float32')
x_v = X_valid.reshape(N3, w, h, 1).astype('float32')

# define data preparation
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) # scales x_t/x_v
train_gen = datagen.flow(x_t, y_train, batch_size=batch_size)
valid_gen = datagen.flow(x_v,y_valid, batch_size=batch_size)



model.fit_generator(train_gen,steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch_tr,validation_data = valid_gen,
                    validation_steps = steps_per_epoch_val,epochs=epochs)
```

This gives an error:

[image]

This is due to expected image dimension error, but I am not sure where/how to fix this. any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks
sedy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the model.fit() case, this line flattened the input before feeding it for training.

x_batch = np.reshape(x_batch, [-1, num_pixels])

But in the generator case, there is nothing to flatten the input before feeding it to the Dense layer. The Dense layer cannot process 2D input (28 x 28). Adding, a Flatten() layer to the model should do the trick as shown below.

```
def baseline_model():

    # create model
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(28,28,1)))
        model.add(Dense(num_pixels, input_dim=num_pixels, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))   
        model.add(Dense(num_classes, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='softmax'))
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model
```

Comment: Thanks, before seeing your comment, I had added model.flatten() at the top( as we normally do at the end of a conv2d->RELU->MAxpool operation), but forgot to specify the input shape (as it is the first layer, so input shape must be specified), and kept on getting weird error. your comment  made me realize my mistake., which i should not have made in the first place.  Also, is there a performance difference expected between Method1 and Method 2?

Comment: I agree the error was not helpful, it was something like model was not compiled.

Comment: With fit_generator there is a multiprocessing option. https://keras.io/models/model/#fit_generator.  "The generator is run in parallel to the model, for efficiency. For instance, this allows you to do real-time data augmentation on images on CPU in parallel to training your model on GPU."